# How do i find the value for a to make det(A)=0? When I solve this my answers are wrong? And I don't know why

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the value of $x$ so that $\operatorname{det}(A)$ is equal to $0$?
So I have to find for what values will $x$ make the determinant of the matrix equal to $0$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
x-2&1\\
-6&x+5
\end{bmatrix}$$

So far what I have done is that I did the formula $ad-bc=0$ and substituted $a$ for $x-2$ and $d$ for $x+5$ and $b$ for $1$ and $c$ for $-6$ and I ended up getting $x^2+3x-4=0$.

Naturally, when I solved for $x$ I got $x = -4$ or $1$.

But when I put these values back to the matrix the determinant does not equal $0$ and as a result I get the answer wrong when I submit it.

Could someone give me guidance on this please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When I plug those in for $x$ I get matrices with $0$ determinant.  Without seeing your work I don't know what is wrong.  Maybe you copied the problem wrong.

Comment: Do a double check on your calculations if you find yourself in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems odd. Let me check: if $x=-4$, then $x-2 = -6$ and $x+5 = 1$. The determinant is therefore equal to $(-6)(1)-(-6)(1) = 0$. If $x=1$ then $x-2=-1$ and $x+5=6$. Again, the determinant will equal $(-1)(6)-(1)(-6) = 0$.

Both your solutions work. You must be making an arithmetical error. What are your exact computations for the determinant?